# Reserved volume serial number

Tags: windows

In windows does there exist a reserved volume serial number, such as `0xFFFFFFFF` or `0x00000000`, which won't be assigned to any volume?

Answer (score 0):

I used this nice little utility written by one of the the former ida devs to change the volume serial of a windows xp vm's volume: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5825/Changing-volume-s-serial-number, and the `vol` command to check.

Windows did not mind me changing it to `0x00000000` or `0xFFFFFFFF`, hence a reserved volume serial number does not appear to exist.